# spring boot Timestamp

Tags: spring, spring-boot

This is my spring boot code.

```
import java.security.Timestamp;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_board")
public class Board {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long bno;
    private String title;
    private String writer;
    private String content;

    @CreationTimestamp
    private Timestamp regdate;
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Timestamp updatedate;
}
```

When I don't write Timestamp this code is free from error.

Do I need dependencies or properties in pom.xml?

But, if I use Timestamp, I can see error.

How can I solve this problem?

And this is error log.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unsupported property type for generator annotation @CreationTimestamp
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
at org.zerock.Boot02Application.main(Boot02Application.java:10) [classes/:na]
```

Comment: java.security.Timestamp . I think this is not correct.

Answer (score 3):

@CreationTimestamp and @UpdateTimestamp can be used with the following attribute types only:

```
java.time.LocalDate (since Hibernate 5.2.3)
java.time.LocalDateTime (since Hibernate 5.2.3)
java.util.Date
java.util.Calendar
java.sql.Date
java.sql.Time
java.sql.Timestamp
```

For more details, go through this link - https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/persist-creation-update-timestamps-hibernate/

Answer (score 1):

Your import is wrong. As @raviiii1 suggested,
instead of `java.security.Timestamp` use `java.sql.Timestamp`

Answer (score 0):

you may try this :

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;


private ZonedDateTime timestamp;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use UTC time, you can try `LocalTime` instead of `Timestamp`

```
import java.time.LocalTime;

localtime = LocalTime.now(ZoneId.of("GMT+08:00"));
```